# Is the category of chain complexes complete and cocomplete in small?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Does the category of chain complexes (let's say of modules over some ring) have all small limits and colimits?

What I understand is that the category of chain complexes is certainly finitely complete and cocomplete, as it is an abelian category.

Comment: Yes, it does. They are computed degreewise.

Comment: @zhen-lin Yes, indeed. I should have spent more time thinking, it seems. Thank you very much.